# Fancybox 2.1.3 not resizing images in WordPress site

Tags: wordpress, resize, fancybox

this is driving me crazy: I have this fancybox 2.1.3 that opens images but if I resize the window the image won't resize. This is weird because everything looks ok in the code and if I use the fancybox to open a blog post it fit and resize nicely. Only Images are f*** up...here the example (not the proper website I'm doing):

http://www.brunoferraroph.altervista.org/wordpress/trattamenti/

javascript settings:

```
defaults: {
        padding : 15,
        margin  : 20,

        width     : 800,
        height    : 600,
        minWidth  : 100,
        minHeight : 100,
        maxWidth  : 9999,
        maxHeight : 9999,

        autoSize   : true,
        autoHeight : false,
        autoWidth  : false,

        autoResize  : true,
        autoCenter  : !isTouch,
        fitToView   : true,
        aspectRatio : false,
        topRatio    : 0.5,
        leftRatio   : 0.5,

        scrolling : 'auto', // 'auto', 'yes' or 'no'
        wrapCSS   : '',
```

fancybox 2.1.4 does the same, css seems working...please help :(

Comment: your demo page doesn't work ... path to images is using `localhost` :/ ... BTW, there is no need to mess with the original js files. You should rather create your own fancybox custom script to override any default setting.

Comment: @JFK you're right, now you can see a proper image popping out...try resizing and you'll see it doesnt work. I dont know Javascript or PHP. Was just wondering why that plugin using fancybox is not working...could you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option autoSize should be setting autoHeight and autoWidth to true by default, but you seem to be overriding them there.  Try setting those to true!

Edit:  Found it!  Set fitToView to true and it works.

Comment: that doesn't work...anyway it's set by default like this. I can't understand what is the problem...but it must be something on css.

Comment: Interesting.  Have you tried the 2.1.4 version?  It's been updated.

Comment: I've been trying every solution but nothing works. I wrote a message to Fancybox contacts...hope they can help :)

Comment: Found the answer, edited my answer above - just set fitToView to true and it works like a charm :)

Comment: Oh god that's true. The main javascript is set like I posted before but inside the plugin, after plugin funcions I had fitToView set by "false". Same for Autosize...totally wasted day. *facepalm* Thanx Tammy your tip got me there.

Comment: Not a problem, glad to help!